Add RxPDO5 CANopen protocol
I am now learning the canopen protocol and I need to add more RxPDO to complete my project. What are the parameters and settings to add more RxPDO5 and RxPDO6?
How can I add RxPDO5 and RxPDO6
What is the Object Index and COB-ID
Please Help
It was a good experience and I hoped my question would be answered

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
